# New (used) monitor -- resolutions not detected and errors when adding them manually

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, xrandr

I just got a used Dell 3007WFP-HC.  I plug it into my Thinkpad X250 running 14.04, go to "displays" and I only have the option of 1280x800 resolution.  I follow [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xrandr) advice on adding undetected resoltions using xrandr.

When I try to add the full 2560x1600 resolution, I get the following errors:

```
xrandr --newmode "2560x1600_60.00"  348.50  2560 2760 3032 3504  1600 1603 1609 1658 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI1 "2560x1600_60.00"
xrandr --output HDMI1 --mode 2560x1600_60.00
xrandr: Configure crtc 1 failed
```

When I try using the GUI, I get the following error:
[image]

when I try to add a 1680x1050 resolution using the same procedure, nothing happens.  I open the display GUI and I see the resolution there, but when I select it, the screen just goes black.

I am using a DVI cable out of the monitor, to an adapter to a mini display port in the laptop.

Is there some driver that I need to download?

I appreciate any help -- I wouldn't which M to go RTFM if I wanted to.

*Update*
When I set the external monitor to a lower framerate using the following, the screen just goes blank, but the display GUI thinks that everything is fine.  The power light on the monitor goes to orange, which is it's "no input" signal.

```
gtf 2560 1600 33
xrandr --newmode "2560x1600_33.00"  182.57  2560 2704 2976 3392  1600 1601 1604 1631  -HSync +Vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI1 "2560x1600_33.00"
xrandr --output HDMI1 --mode 2560x1600_33.00
```

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that this is not an ubuntu problem as such.  I needed an active adapter to translate the DVI signal to the mini-dp signal.  Buying this thing worked for me:
http://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B004I6L6DW?psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00